# Why are these pymunk collision points in unexpected places

Tags: python, pymunk

I have a pymunk simulation with the world space defined as segments:

```
    static_body = space.static_body
    walls = [
        pymunk.Segment(static_body, (0, 0), (0, 1500), 0.0),
        pymunk.Segment(static_body, (0, 1500), (1500, 1500), 0.0),
        pymunk.Segment(static_body, (1500, 1500), (1500, 500), 0.0),
        pymunk.Segment(static_body, (1500, 500), (1000, 500), 0.0),
        pymunk.Segment(static_body, (1000, 500), (1000, 0), 0.0),
        pymunk.Segment(static_body, (1000, 0), (0, 0), 0.0),
    ]
    for wall in walls:
        wall.collision_type = 3
    space.add(*walls)
```

I have a sensor object, defined as a poly:

```
        sensor_shape = pymunk.Poly(None, [
              (-5 + x_offset, 0 + y_offset),
              (-20 + x_offset, sensor_depth + y_offset), 
              (20 + x_offset, sensor_depth + y_offset),
              (5 + x_offset, 0 + y_offset)])
        sensor_shape.sensor = True
        sensor_shape.collision_type = 1
        self.sensor_shape = sensor_shape
```

This is attached to a body with non sensor shapes. The space has a collision handler:

```
sensor_collision_handler = space.add_collision_handler(1, 3)
sensor_collision_handler.pre_solve = robot.sensor_pre_solve
```

In the pre_solve, I walk through the collision points if the sensor shape is in the arbiter shapes:

```
        if self.sensor_shape in arbiter.shapes:
            self.last_contact_points = []
            for point in arbiter.contact_point_set.points:
                self.last_contact_points.append(point.point_a)
                self.last_contact_points.append(point.point_b)
```

In the draw section I am attempting to draw circles these contact points:

```
        for contact_point in robot.last_contact_points:
          contact_location = pymunk.pygame_util.to_pygame(draw_options.transform @ contact_point, screen)
          pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), contact_location, 10)
```

The transform in the draw options scales and moves the space a little:

```
    draw_options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(screen)
    draw_options.transform = pymunk.Transform.scaling(0.5) @ pymunk.Transform.translation(250, 250)
```

The contact points *are* on the boundaries of the shapes involved, but they are not at the locations where they intersect. In the pictures below, the blue box is the main body the sensor is attached to. Yes - I'm aware the sensor and robot body sometimes collide. however, it is the collision points between the sensor and the segment shapes of the space that look wrong to me.

[image: Contact points in wrong places]
[image: Close but still off]

Comment: Hmm - I see a close vote. Please explain?

Comment: Unfortunately I think that when shapes are overlapping much you cant do what you want. But the exact details as to why is a bit outside my knowledge.